# How to make a window always appear on top of other windows?

Tags: mfc

In my dialog I have a rich edit control. While typing in the richeditcontrol, I am displaying a list box for auto completion.

I want to display the listbox on top of other windows but my listbox is not visible fully but it is forced to be inside of richedit control.

**I want to implement like  listbox in combobox which is always top of other windows**.

How  to display the listbox on top of other window?

I am displaying below styles.

```
DWORD nListStyle = WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_EX_TOPMOST|WS_CHILD |WS_VISIBLE|LBS_NOTIFY|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|WS_BORDER|
LBS_OWNERDRAWVARIABLE|LBS_HASSTRINGS| LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT; 
m_ctrlListBox.Create(nListStyle , listBoxRect, this,IDC_LIST);
```

[image]

Comment: ["_A child window has the WS_CHILD style and is confined to the client area of its parent window._"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#child).

Comment: You don't want a window, *"which is always top of other windows"*. You want an [owned window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows).

Comment: @IInspectable - I am unable to use WS_POPUP in the m_ctrlListBox.Create function I am getting assertion.ASSERT((dwStyle & WS_POPUP) == 0);

Comment: Solution is simple: Create a `CWnd` instance with `WS_POPUP`, create `CListBox` instance as child of the `CWnd`. You propably also want `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` for the `CWnd`, so the keyboard focus stays with the edit control.

Comment: @zett42- As you said I created CWnd with WS_POPUP and WS_EX_NOACTIVATE styles and CListBox instance as child of CWnd.But I am unable to type in the CRichEditCtrl until I set focus on it. In the OnLButtonDown event of richedit control I am destroying CWnd and CListBox so they both getting hided once I set focus on CRichEditCTrl.

Comment: @zett42 - One doubt I need to do selection in listbox in that case can I use WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style.

Comment: "_I am unable to type in the CRichEditCtrl until I set focus on it_" -- Try to create `CWnd` without `WS_VISIBLE`, show it with `SetWindowPos()` using `SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOACTIVATE`. "_One doubt I need to do selection in listbox in that case can I use WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style._" -- Mouse selection in listbox should work fine, for keyboard selection you have to forward keyboard messages (e. g. up/down key) from `CRichEditCtrl` to `CListBox`.

Comment: Use an Edit control for auto completion [SHAutoComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759862(v=vs.85).aspx)