# How to catch move event of dialog?

Tags: mfc

In my dialog I have a rich edit control. While typing in the richeditcontrol, I am displaying a list box for auto completion.

To display this listbox, top of all child controls in the dialog, as suggested in this link, [How to make a window always appear on top of other windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604923/how-to-make-a-window-always-appear-on-top-of-other-windows?noredirect=1#comment88304291_50604923)
I created a CWnd instance with WS_POPUP and created CListBox instance as child of that CWnd.

Now When I move the dialog or changing position, I need to change the position of the popup window and the listbox which I created.

I tried to catch the on_wm_poschanged, on_move and onsize events when moving the dialog but none is triggered ?

How to catch move event of dialog?

My dialog has ws_child style.
This is my message map.

```
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyChildDlg, CMyDlg)
        ON_WM_SIZE()
        ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING()
        ON_WM_MOVING()
        ON_MOVE()
        ON_WM_WINDOWSPOSCHANGED()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyChildDlg::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) 
{
    CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
}

void CMyChildDlg::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS FAR* lpwndpos) 
{
     CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);

}

void CMyChildDlg::OnMove(int x, int y)
{
    CDialog::OnMove(nType, cx, cy);
}

void CMyChildDlg::OnMoving(UINT nSide, LPRECT lpRect)
{
    CDialog::OnMoving(nSide, lpRect);
}

void CMyChildDlg::OnWindowPosChanged(WINDOWPOS FAR* lpwndpos) 
{
     CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpwndpos);
}
```

but these events are not getting captured while moving the dialog.

Comment: Did you put `ON_WM_SIZE()` in the message map? Please show some code, especially the message map of the dialog.

Comment: I tried ON_WM_SIZE()
ON_WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING()
ON_WM_MOVING() ON_WM_MOVE() ON_WM_WINDOWSPOSCHANDED. These events are not getting captured while moving the dialog.

Comment: Please don't post code in a comment but [edit] your question instead. And show more code. And show real code, not some retyped out of context  fragments.

Comment: There is not enough information, you need to post a [MCVE]. This means some work for you.

Comment: A child window doesn't receive notifications when the parent is moved, because the child window's coordinates do not change relative to the parent. You have to catch these in the parent.